# Creating a figure of distributions on parallel sheets

Tags: plotting

Is there a way to recreate a similar image as below in Mathematica? In the figure it is a distribution that is continuous in one dimension and discrete in another. I'm looking not so much to defining a distribution function with that property, but just creating a similar figure of distributions on parallel sheets as they described.

---

### [image]

*Image Source: "Actuarial Mathematics", 2nd Edition, Bowers et al, pg 309*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust as needed:

```
f1[x_] := x^2 + Sin[x];
f2[x_] := .4 x^2 + .2 Sin[x + .3];
f3[x_] := .8 x^2 + Cos[2 x];
f1fig = ParametricPlot3D[{x, 0, z},
   {x, 0, 1}, {z, 0, f1[x]},
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Yellow],
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}];
f2fig = ParametricPlot3D[{x, .5, f2[x]},
   {x, 0, 1},
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.02]],
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}];
f3fig = ParametricPlot3D[{x, 1.5, z},
   {x, 0, 1}, {z, 0, f3[x]},
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Blue],
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}];
Show[f3fig, f2fig, f1fig]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you!